# Print multiple side by side pyramid patterns in C

Tags: c

So basically, I want to make a pyramid pattern using "*" just like normal, but this time the amount of pyramid isn't only one, but the same as the input. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, row, space, star, n;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if(i>0 && i<100){
        for(n=1; n<=i; n++){
            for(row = 1; row<=i; row++){
                int mathforspace = i-row;
                int mathforstar = (2*row)-1;
                //print spaces
                for(space=1; space<=mathforspace; space++){
                printf(" ");
                }
                //print stars
                for(star=1; star<=mathforstar; star++)
                printf("*");
                //print newline
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, i managed to print it, but it makes a newline everytime its making another pyramid, how can i make it so that it goes sideways? thanks!

Comment: Side note: I suggest that you replace `if(i>0 && i<100){` with `if( i<0 || i > 100) { printf( "Error, out of range!\n" ); return 1; }` That way, you don't need an extra level of indentation for the rest of your program.

Comment: If you cannot jump around on the terminal/console with the cursor (which plain ISO C does not allow, but most operating systems actually do allow you to do that using platform-specific interfaces), then you will have to print all `n` pyramids at the same time, instead of one after another. You will first have to print the first line of the first pyramid, then the first line of the second pyramid, then the first line of the third pyramid, until you have printed the first line of all pyramids. Afterwards, you print a newline character and then start printing the second line of all pyramids.

Comment: Simplest is to create "frame buffer", that is a two-dimensional char array. Then draw (with chars) anything you want there. Then print it when all drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing one row at a time and within a single row print all the `n` occurrences of the strides of hashtags you need.
You need to separate each stride by the same amount of spaces you separate a row in your code from the left side of the screen;

[DEMO on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VifffY6LyvL9JkfL)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPyramids(const int i) {
  int row, space, hashtag, n;
  for (row = 1; row <= i; row++) {

    for (n = 0; n < i; n++) {
      const int mathspace = i - row;
      const int mathhashtag = (2 * row) - 1;
      // print spaces
      for (space = 1; space <= mathspace; space++) {
        printf(" ");
      }
      // print hashtag
      for (hashtag = 1; hashtag <= mathhashtag; hashtag++)
        printf("#");
      
       //Instead of printing new line, separate the next stride by mathspace spaces
      for (space = 1; space <= mathspace; space++) {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int i;
  scanf("%d", &i);

  if (i <= 0 || i >= 100) {
        printf("Invalid input");
        return 0;
    
  }
  
  printPyramids(i);
  return 0;
}
```

For `n = 5` it outputs:

```
    #        #        #        #        #    
   ###      ###      ###      ###      ###   
  #####    #####    #####    #####    #####  
 #######  #######  #######  #######  ####### 
#############################################
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to work with *trees* limited to about 30 (or 62???) characters wide (the largest would require ~4000 characters on a single line) there's simple way to achieve this. Use a bit mask to control outputting either ' ' or '#', and repeat and repeat. After each line is printed, shifting & or'ing the mask with itself adds width to the '#'s that will be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void fun( int n ) {
    uint32_t mask = 1 << n;
    
    for( int r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        for( int d = 0; d < n; d++ ) {
            for( int c = 1; c < 2*n; c++ )
                putchar( "# "[!((1<<c) & mask)] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
        mask |= (mask<<1) | (mask>>1);
    }
}

int main() {
    for( int i = 1; i <= 7; i += 2 ) {
        printf( "\n%d:\n", i );
        fun( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1:
#

3:
  #    #    #
 ###  ###  ###
###############

5:
    #        #        #        #        #
   ###      ###      ###      ###      ###
  #####    #####    #####    #####    #####
 #######  #######  #######  #######  #######
#############################################

7:
      #            #            #            #            #            #            #
     ###          ###          ###          ###          ###          ###          ###
    #####        #####        #####        #####        #####        #####        #####
   #######      #######      #######      #######      #######      #######      #######
  #########    #########    #########    #########    #########    #########    #########
 ###########  ###########  ###########  ###########  ###########  ###########  ###########
###########################################################################################
```

Is anyone else feeling the twinges of Christmas approaching?

```
void fun( int n ) {
    uint32_t mask = 1 << n;
    
    for( int r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        for( int d = 0; d < 140; d += 2*n ) {
            for( int c = 0; c < 2*n; c++ )
                putchar( " #"[!((1<<c) & mask)] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
        mask |= (mask<<1) | (mask>>1);
    }
}

int main() {
    for( int i = 1; i <= 8; i++ )
        fun( i );

    return 0;
}
```